# Qt how to get the target information of the shortcut？

Tags: qt

[image: how_to_get]
How to use Qt to get the target content of the shortcut?
Cannot find using`QString QFileInfo::symLinkTarget() const`.
How can I find information about `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /A /Q /K D:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtenv2.bat`

Comment: To get help about `cmd.exe`, open a command console and type `cmd.exe /?`. It will provide a short help. (Not that a google search would help as well.) If you need help about `D:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtenv2.bat` - it's a batch file. So, just open it in a plain text editor of your choice. (Or google it - it might be documented in the Qt online doc.) Btw. what does it have to do with `QFileInfo::symLinkTarget()`? (May be, I would understand better if I could read Chinese but I can't.)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a `.lnk` shortcut file.

If you try to open that shortcut, you open the target instead.

Googling 'windows analyze .lnk file' gets you some good hints, especially [this howtogeek.com article](https://www.howtogeek.com/190897/how-can-you-open-and-edit-windows-.lnk-shortcut-files/) lists interesting details:

> The whole point of a .lnk file is for Windows to treat it as a link to another file, so it should be hard to edit! Perhaps it would help if you described why you want to edit it. You can change the settings of a .lnk file by right-clicking and choosing Properties.
>
> If you really want to edit it, you need a special tool. [...]

For a quick look at the contents of such a file the difficult part is to open it in an (hex) editor. The article describes a simple method:

> As a workaround, open a command prompt and rename the .lnk file with a different, non-existent extension such as .lne:
>
> ```
> cd /d “X:\Folder\containing\the\shortcut”
> ren “some shortcut.lnk” “some shortcut.lne”
> ```

Qt treats these shortcuts as symbolic links, see [the docs for `QFileInfo::isSymLink()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#isSymLink):

> In addition, true will be returned for shortcuts (*.lnk files) on Windows. Opening those will open the .lnk file itself.

*So answering your original question*:
`QFileInfo` has no option to show the 'content' of a .lnk file.
Furthermore, analyzing a .lnk file via `QFileInfo` always analyzes the target the shortcut is pointing to.